# UITableView with Custom Cell and Separator. Alpha value changes on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, alpha

I have a `UITableView` with a `Custom Cell`. Some custom cells are being loaded with an image. 
And I'm adding a custom separator for the cells that have an image. The problem arises on scrolling. Whenever I scroll, the `UIView` `opacity` changes.

Here is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}  

if (cell && (NSNull*) imageString != [NSNull null])
{
    UIView* separatorLineView; = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -1, 320, 5)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    separatorLineView.alpha = 0.2;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
}
```

`Alpha` for the view given is `0.2` and on scrolling it becomes thicker and thicker. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: add the separator in custom cell view controller

Comment: The problem is that you keep adding new subviews over and over as the cells get reused during scrolling. Only add the subview once per cell.

Comment: do what @rmaddy and @rdelmar have suggested but since you're using a custom cell anyways, the quickest way, imho, would be to add this line to the cell's contentView via the Interface Builder directly. Call it `vwLine` or something and set it's `hidden` property to `YES`. Then while doing your `imageString != [NSNull null]` check, do `[cell.vwLine setHidden:NO];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what @rmaddy and @rdelmar have suggested but since you're using a custom cell anyways, the quickest way, imho, would be:

1. Add this line to the cell's `contentView` via the **Interface Builder** directly

   - `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *vwLine;`

     - also `@synthesize vwLine;`
   - Set it's frame, background color & alpha value (*obviously*)
   - **Set it's `hidden` property to `YES`**
2. When you do the `imageString != [NSNull null]` check

   - if TRUE then `[cell.vwLine setHidden:NO];`

### Example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell"
                                                                 owner:self
                                                               options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }  

    if (imageString != [NSNull null]) {
        [cell.vwLine setHidden:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're adding a separatorLineView to cells that already have one as you scroll, so what you're seeing is lines on top of other lines. You could fix that by adding a tag to your line view, and checking if the cell has a subview with that tag, and if so, don't add another line.

Answer (score 0):

In your code might be problem of reusability of cell. So try with following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    . 
    .
    .
    .
    if(cell == nil)
    {
       NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
       cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

      if(cellHasImage == YES)
      {
         //// just initialize UIView and add as addSubview of cell.contentView
         UIView* separatorLineView; = [[UIView alloc] init];
         separatorLineView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -1, 320, 5);
         separatorLineView.tag = 111; // set whatever you like
         [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
      }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    /// get UIView base on it's tag
    if(cellHasImage == YES)
    { 
       UIView* separatorLineView; = (UIView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:111];
       separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       separatorLineView.alpha = 0.2;
     }

    .
    .
    .

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i didn't downvote but whoever did that, did for the right reason. your code is buggy. **[1]** When the `tableView` loads for the first time, none of the cells will show a `separatorLineView` irrespective of whether the cell has an image or not, until the user scrolls significantly (_not what the OP is trying to accomplish_) & this will be problematic if the number of cells is small. _These are minor issues but..._ **[2]** You're unnecessarily setting the same property multiple times (_the `backgroundColor` and `alpha` in the `else` block_). **[3]** (_super minor issue_) there is no `setFrame`.

Comment: @staticVoidMan - really thanks mate .. for clear me :) but your 3rd indication is very right ... :)

Comment: no issues :) btw... your edit is still buggy. it relates to the cell reusability scenario. it's possible that cells with no image will show the separator (_i.e. if it reuses a cell that previously contained an image_) and cells with images will not show show the seperator (_i.e. if it reuses a cell that previously did not contain an image_). it's quite a buggy scenario.